# Increment 7 days to a date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Explanation of my my objective**: By the press of a button in my google sheets, add 7 days to a currently exsting date in a cell.

**What currently happens**: When I press to run my script instead of adding 7 days it simply writes 7 at then end.

**My script**:

```
function IncrementW() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue() + 7);
};
```

**What the output gives me:**

```
From: 7/12/2020 to >> Sun Jul 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)7
```

**What my output should be**:

```
From: 7/12/2020 to >> 7/19/2020
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getValue()` returns a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object(which gets converted to `string`, when used with the `+` operator). Use [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) to setDate:

```
function IncrementW() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cell = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  const dt = cell.getValue();
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7);
  cell.setValue(dt);
};
```

Comment: When I try your new function it returns **1595131200000**. At first I thought it was a formating issue but it doesn't seem like it is. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cruxer I edited it shortly after posting. Try the new answer